# Working with character values beyond ChrW(65535) in VbScript

Tags: vbscript

Does VBScript have any way to support converting hex to decimal to char beyond the range of `ChrW(65535)`?

For example, `\u2122` is `h&2122` (hex), and converts to decimal value `8482`, which, using `ChrW` prints `™`

```
Response.Write ChrW(cLng("&h2122"))
```

Results in:

```
™
```

... All good so far.

There are characters beyond the range of `ChrW`  e.g. the "[G clef](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d11e/index.htm)" character `U+1D11E` (utf-16) which maps to decimal 119,070, which is beyond the range of `ChrW()`

Is there a way to work with those higher characters in `VBScript`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the surrogate pair encoded values for the utf16-le (or utf16-be) encoding of that character and give'em to two separate chrW calls and concat the result.

```
Dim tmChar
tmChar = ChrW(&HD834) & ChrW(&HDD1E)
' You will probably see just a square or a question mark or some place holder here, depending on system and font support
MSGBox("Wow: " & tmChar)
'Have also a thinking face emoji as an additional example
tmChar = ChrW(&HD83E) & ChrW(&HDD14)
MSGBox("Hummm... " & tmChar)
```

I think vbs strings store utf16-le "units" , not characters nor codepoints.

Note that:
  "G clef" is the unicode character corresponding to the code point number 119070 (1D11E in hexadecimal)
  "G clef" is U+1D11E Unicode *stop*
  "G clef" as surrogate pair units is 0xD834 0xDD1E
  "G clef" encoded as UTF16-BE is 0xD8 0x34 0xDD 0x1E
  "G clef" encoded as UTF16-LE is 0x34 0xD8 0x1E 0xDD